# Can not install Matplotlib on OS X El Capitan with pip

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

When I tried to install matplotlib
by typing "pip install matplotlib"

It keeps throwing following error messages. Can anyone help me?

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 311, in run
root=options.root_path,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 646, in install
**kwargs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 803, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 998, in move_wheel_files
isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 339, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
os.utime(destfile, (st.st_atime, st.st_mtime))
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py'
```

Comment: i'm not a mac person, but do you have root privileges?

Comment: Do you have all dependencies installed?

Comment: try `sudo pip install matplotlib`

Comment: `sudo pip install matplotlib` did the trick!! thank you borja!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

solve it for me!

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help people to understand the problem.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am using OS X El Captain and had the same issue. 
I used :-

```
conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib=1.5.2
```

Matplot lib got installed and there is no import error. But still there is an error related to pyplot which I am guessing is more of a OS X El Captain compatibility  issue .

You can find more information related to the error here and may be also help me in solving it :-

[Ipython/ pylab/ matplotlib installation and initialization error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38564507/ipython-pylab-matplotlib-installation-and-initialization-error)